# How to get http response header with okhttp3 and decide whether to get response body

Tags: header, response, okhttp

I want to use the response header to determine whether or not to get the response body, the scenario is like this, I need to determine whether or not the session in the response header expires to determine whether or not to continue to download the file.If the session expires, simply cancel the download.

I looked at okhttp's interceptor and felt it didn't meet my requirements.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Interceptor interceptor = new Interceptor() {
        @Override
        public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
            //拦截
            Response originalResponse = chain.proceed(chain.request());


            Headers headers = originalResponse.headers();
            if (callback != null){
                callback.onCallBack(headers,downloadId);
            }

            //包装响应体并返回
            return originalResponse
                    .newBuilder()
                    .body(new ProgressResponseBody(originalResponse.body(), progressListener))
                    .build();
        }
    };
    return client.newBuilder()
            .addInterceptor(interceptor)
            .build();
```